# Round numbers of different lengths to nearest 0 or 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

How to round numbers of different length size to the nearest zero or five?

Example:

```
1291 -> 1290
0.069 -> 0.07
1.08 -> 1.1
14 -> 15
6 -> 5
```

Tried to use round() and math.ceil() / math.floor() but since the numbers are different each time in length I can’t adapt it dynamically, numbers are returning from a function not an array.

Comment: Find the rule: it _looks_ like you're rounding "any decimal number to one fewer decimals, and every integer to the nearest factor of 5". If that's your rule, then we now by definition have what we need to start implementing that: we need two different code paths, one for decimal numbers, and one for integer number. But also, this is a _really weird_ rounding requirement, what on earth are you doing that needs this?

Comment: Hi Mike! I’m doing API calls for crypto trading and when computing the trade size for different pairs some of them requires the size to be a multiple of 10

Comment: Why don't you write your own function for this ? use repr and then check the last digit using if else.

Comment: There is a mathematical way of doing it, even one or two lines, but it's mad ugly because you include floating points :(

Comment: @no_hex it's python, so... no it's not. We have `x = u if v else w` and then we write nice functions/lambdas to keep the code legible.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't quite get what you are trying to say - one liner it isn't or if it is, it's super ugly, but meh, it will be an ugly calculation anyways (or else I am too tired to think of a better way)

Comment: @user21057728 I have a solution, it is ugly. Do you need a solution at all costs or you need a pythonic nice way of doing so?

Comment: @no_hex, A proper function will be beneficial for futures users having the same problem

Comment: Just break it out into multiple functions based on `is_integer()`, done. It'll look clean, it'll run perfectly fast enough, it'll be good Python code.

Comment: The rounding to 0-or-5 is easy: divide by 5, round, multiply by 5. The tricky part is know how many decimal places to round to (or equivalently, knowing what power of 10 to multiply by to get an integer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are, thanks for the other solutions:

```
import math
import decimal

def round_half_up(n):
    if (str(n).find(".") > 0):
        decimalsource = len(str(n).split(".")[1])
        base = 10**decimalsource
        number = n*base
        rounded = 5 * round(number/5)
        result = rounded / base
        if (result == int(result)):
            return int(result)
        else:
            return result
    else:
        return 5 * round(n/5)

      
print(round_half_up(1291))
print(round_half_up(0.069))
print(round_half_up(1.08))
print(round_half_up(14))
print(round_half_up(6))
print(round_half_up(12.121213))
print(round_half_up(12.3))
print(round_half_up(18.))
print(round_half_up(18))
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a code and explained. It seems working. I didn't take into account negative numbers.

```
import numpy as np
convDict = {
    "0":"0",
    "1":"0",
    "2":"0",
    "3":"5",
    "4":"5",
    "5":"5",
    "6":"5",
    "7":"5",
    "8":"0",
    "9":"0"
}

def conv(f):
    str_f = str(f)
    
    # if input is like, 12. or 13.0,so actually int but float data type
    # We will get rid of the .0 part
    if str_f.endswith(".0"):
        str_f = str(int(f))

    # We need last character, and other body part
    last_f = str_f[-1]
    body_f = str_f[:-1]

    # if last char is 8 or 9 we should increment body last value
    if last_f in "89":
        # Number of decimals
        numsOfDec = body_f[::-1].find('.')

        # numsOfDec = -1 means body is integer, we will add 1
        if numsOfDec == -1:
            body_f = str(int(body_f) + 1)

        else:
            # We will add 10 ** -numsOfDec , but it can lead some numerical differences like 0.69999, so i rounded
            body_f = str(np.round(float(body_f) + 10 ** (-numsOfDec),numsOfDec))

    # Finally we round last char
    last_f = convDict[last_f]
    return float(body_f + last_f)
```

And some examples,

```
print(conv(1291))
print(conv(0.069))
print(conv(1.08))
print(conv(14))
print(conv(6))
print(conv(12.121213))
print(conv(12.3))
print(conv(18.))
print(conv(18))
```

Comment: Actually `print(conv(12.1999999))` is `12.2` . Is it okay for your case?

Answer (score 0):

The kinda pythonic way to round dynamically to nearest five would be to use round() function and input number (divided by 5), the index in which you want the rounding to ocurr [-2: hundreds, -1: tens, 0: whole, 1:1/10ths, 2:1/100s] and multiply result by 5. You can calculate this index by finding how many decimal places there are using decimal module.

```
 i = decimal.Decimal('0.069')
 i.as_tuple().exponent
 -3
```

Note that this function takes the number as a string and outputs the number
of decimal places in negative.

After getting this number, make it positive, and there you have the calculated index to put into the round function in the beginning.

```
round(0.069/5, 3) * 5
```

You need to also check before all this calculation if the number is a full number (meaning no decimal places--17, 290, 34.0) (in that case you shouldn't use above code at all), which you can easily do by using modulus, so the overall function would look like this:

```
 if number % 1 == 0:
     return round(int(number)/5)*5
 else:
     index = decimal.Decimal(str(number)).as_tuple().exponent
     return round(number/5, -index)*5
```

Hope this helped !